# Can I use Timeseries of a Data to plot the ARCHProcess?

Tags: date-and-time, time-series, finance

So,
I have a list

```
s={Timeseries1,Timeseries2,Timeseris3}
```

I want to Plot a graph just like :[Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/expanded-time-series-processes/model-the-conditional-value-at-risk-with-an-archpr.html)

I tried to do this but I didn't understand some parts of the code.Can someone help me understand this part of the code in Image?
Thanks.

This is the screenshot of the error that I get when I run it.

Code:

```
applFirst = 
 TimeSeriesWindow[archTslist[[1]], {Automatic, {2021, 06, 19}}]
applLast = 
 TimeSeriesWindow[archTslist[[1]], {{2020, 06, 20}, Automatic}]

model = TimeSeriesModelFit[applFirst, "ARCH"]

eproc = model["BestFit"]
{\[Kappa], {a, b}} = List @@ eproc
ARCHProcess[932925.0531588219`, {0.7230289327003918`, 
  0.2656890200569876`}]
{932925.0531588219`, {0.7230289327003918`, 0.2656890200569876`}}
\[Alpha] = .05;
quantile = Quantile[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 1 - \[Alpha]];
VaR = MovingMap[Sqrt[\[Kappa] + {a, b} . (#^2)] quantile &, applLast, 
  2]
DateListPlot[{applLast, VaR}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> {"returns", "value at risk"}]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Please provide the full code you are using (including ``a, b, \[Kappa]`` ...), and include it in a copy-pastable way as text (not as a screenshot).

Comment: The problem lies in calculating ``VarR`` where you have ``{a, b} . (#^2)``. 

Because you set the window in ``MovingMap`` as 2, this is interpreted by Mathematica as **2 days**! However, in your timeseries, there seems to be 3 datapoints during 2 days. This means that the dot product cannot be calculated, because you want to multiply a 2-vector with a 3-vector. 

If you want to have a moving map with 2 datapoints, you have to change it to:
``VaR = MovingMap[Sqrt[\[Kappa] + {a, b} . (#^2)] quantile &, applLast, Quantity[2, "Events"]]``.